# Create a manual fiscal year from an order/transaction date in COGNOS Analytics using a CASE Statement

Tags: cognos-11

I'm trying to use a Data Item to create fiscal year, financial Quarter and financial periods from a data entry [Txn Date] in COGNOS. As I'm limited on what I can do as there is no calendar table to take from I need to try and create the financial headers manually using the [Txn Date] from the data entry within the tables that I do have access to.

I'm also a novice user of COGNOS and CASE statements do any instruction/examples given would need to be simple.

Example of outcome:
Data entry [Txn Date],
`FY ([Txn Date] = 12/04/2023 then FY 23-24)`
`FY Qtr([Txn Date] = 12/01/2023 then Qtr 1)`
`FY Period ([Txn Date] = 12/01/2023 then AP 1)`

I'm hoping this makes sense as my knowledge of COGNOS is limited and this is driving me nuts trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

> > I'm also a novice user of COGNOS and CASE statements do any
> > instruction/examples given would need to be simple.
> > Sure,

Here is the information for
case expression { when expression then expression } [ else expression ] end
Works with when, then, else, and end. Case identifies the beginning of a specific situation, in which when, then, and else actions are defined.

For example,

```
case
when ([Year] = extract(year, current_date))Then('Current')
else ('Previous')
end
```

Comment: Great.  If you like the answer, click the up arrow to show the answer was useful